# Recursively add value to an array

Tags: php, recursion, codeigniter-3

I want to get the child element ids to an array.
From my table, id 5 is the parent of id (4, 11) and id 4 is the parent of id 9.
if I call ***childCategoryIds()*** function with id 5, it should return [11, 9, 4], but
it is returning [11, 4]. My function and sql data look like the following:

Table:

```
id  parent_id   name        
4   5           Cat Four    
5   1           Cat Five    
9   4           Cat Nine
11  5           Cat Eleven
```

my function:

```
function childCategoryIds($id){
    $ci = & get_instance();
    $ci->load->database();

    $child_category_ids = array();

    $ci->db->where('parent_id', $id)->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $query = $ci->db->get('categories');
    $result = $query->result();
    foreach ($result as $res):
        childCategoryIds($res->id);
        $child_category_ids[] = $res->id;
     // var_dump($res->id);
    endforeach;

    return $child_category_ids;
}
```

I have call this function from my controller.

```
childCategoryIds(5);    /* here id = 5 */
```

From the function **$child_category_ids** return id (11, 4). but **var_dump($res->id)** shows all ids (11, 9, 4) into the loop. As I understand, the loop run only once into the function or when the function call itself into the loop, it fails to push it's id to **$child_category_ids**.

I got the following result from this function.

```
array(2) {
    [0] => string(2) "11" 
    [1] => string(1) "4"
}
```

but my expected result is:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => string(2) "11" 
    [1] => string(1) "9"
    [2] => string(1) "4"
}
```

I have got some similar questions, but couldn't get the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is scope, the variables declared in your function aren't seen outside of it (even when called recursively). if you dump out `childCategoryIds($res->id);` you'd probably see the info if being retrieved, just not stored in the array.

you could try something like `array_merge` to pull the data into the same array, or simply loop through the results and add them in as below:

```php
$result = $query->result();
foreach ($result as $res):

    $children = childCategoryIds($res->id);
    $child_category_ids = array_merge($child_category_ids, $children);

    $child_category_ids[] = $res->id;
    // var_dump($res->id);
endforeach;
```

or

```php
$result = $query->result();
foreach ($result as $res):

    $children = childCategoryIds($res->id);
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $child_category_ids [] = $child;
    }

    $child_category_ids[] = $res->id;
    // var_dump($res->id);
endforeach;
```